# GetWeekOfYear returns wrong result?

Tags: c#, .net

Week 1 of 2013 starts 31-12-2012 since it's a monday.

A call to `GetWeekOfYear` with culture `nl-NL`, `FirstDayOfWeek.Monday` and `CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek` returns week number 53 for monday 31-12-2012 and week 1 for tuesday 1-1-2013. How can that monday have a different week number than tuesday?

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Because it's week 53 of 2012.  It will return the week of the year passed in, based on the date you use (`31-12-2012`).  Week 1 of 2013 is the same week as week 53 of 2012.

Comment: I get it. The function isn't returning a value people normally use when they look at weeknumbers at a calendar. Do you know how to get the right week number? After all to most people week 1 still starts 31-12-2012.

Comment: I used this custom function. Which works. http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2005/09/26/iso-weeknumbers-of-a-date-a-c-implementation/. But i still don't get what the use is of the function GetWeekOfYear.

Comment: @Jeroen The first week of the year does start then - but you'd have to just compute when the monday <= Jan 1 happens to be if you want to report that.

Answer (score 0):

The year you have passed in your first example is 2012. Not 2013. It's returning the week of the year you have passed in your date.

Comment: How is that usefull? When i look at my paper calendar it says week 1 for 31-12-2012. Why would anyone want if differently?

Comment: @Jeroen That same calendar, if it shows 2012, will show 01-01-2013 as week 53 of 2012, too ;)

Comment: In my country (nl-NL) week 52 ends 30-12-2012 and week 1 starts 31-12-2012. Maybe in others countries is different. That's ok. That's what we have CultureCodes for :)